# Illegal unit of measure error when using hyperref in the ifacconf class

Tags: errors, hyperref, incompatibility

I'm trying to submit an article to an IFAC conference by using their template: https://www.ifac-control.org/events/author-guide/copy_of_ifacconf_latex.zip/view.
I also want to use the `hyperref` package to add links to the document, in addition to the `autoref` macros, among other features.
My document compiles just fine using `latexmk` before adding the `hyperref` package, but generates the following errors when it is added:

```
Errors:

./mwe-delete.tex:33: Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). [\begin{ack}]
./mwe-delete.bbl:1: Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). [\begin{thebibliography}{1}]
```

For clarity, I work with the following files:

- `mwe-delete.tex` MWE main tex file.
- `refs-test-delete.bib` MWE bibliography file.

Additionally, the file `mwe-delete.bbl` is generated by `natbib`.

These are the contents of `mwe-delete.tex`:

```
\documentclass{ifacconf}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}
\title{Paper Title\thanksref{titlenote}}

\thanks[titlenote]{
    Titlenote.
}

\author[First]{First Author}

\address[First]{First Author contact info.}

\begin{abstract}
The abstract.
\end{abstract}

\begin{keyword}
Keyword
\end{keyword}

\end{frontmatter}

\section{Introduction}
\label{sec:introduction}

Introduction.
This is based on the work of \citet{bibref1}.

\begin{ack}
Acknowledgement.
\end{ack}

\bibliography{refs-test-delete}

\end{document}
```

The contents of `refs-test-delete.bib`:

```
@Article{bibref1,
  author    = {Firstname M. Lastname},
  title     = {PaperTitle},
  journal   = {Journal of Journals},
  year      = {2009},
  volume    = {32},
  number    = {3},
  pages     = {1039--1045},
  month     = {5},
  publisher = {Publisher},
}
```

The generated contents in `mwe-delete.bbl`:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{1}
\providecommand{\natexlab}[1]{#1}
\providecommand{\url}[1]{\texttt{#1}}
\providecommand{\urlprefix}{URL }
\expandafter\ifx\csname urlstyle\endcsname\relax
  \providecommand{\doi}[1]{doi:\discretionary{}{}{}#1}\else
  \providecommand{\doi}{doi:\discretionary{}{}{}\begingroup
  \urlstyle{rm}\Url}\fi

\bibitem[{Lastname(2009)}]{bibref1}
Lastname, F.M. (2009).
\newblock Papertitle.
\newblock \emph{Journal of Journals}, 32(3), 1039--1045.

\end{thebibliography}
```

Does anyone have any experience using the IFAC template together with `hyperref`?
I'm using TexLive 2017 with the latest updated packages.
The contents of `ifacconf.cls` are found [here (direct link to .zip-file of 460 kB)](https://www.ifac-control.org/events/author-guide/copy_of_ifacconf_latex.zip/at_download/file).

Comment: I got  the same error when using \usepackage{pdfcomment}.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The fundamental difference here is that [`ifacconf`](https://www.ifac-control.org/events/author-guide/copy_of_ifacconf_latex.zip/at_download/file) updates the way sections are formatted/presented by introducing a new internal argument aimed at distinguishing between certain headings. Specifically, "headings at a level lower than 1" are formatted one way, while "headings at a level of 1 or higher" are formatted differently. And, since [`hyperref`](//ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) loads [`nameref`](//ctan.org/pkg/nameref) in order to grab sectional unit titles, there is some confusion between the usual way and the `ifacconf` way.

A more direct explanation: LaTeX handles `\section*` via the macro `\@ssect`:

```
\def\@ssect#1#2#3#4#5{%
  \@tempskipa #3\relax
  \ifdim \@tempskipa>\z@
    \begingroup
      #4{%
        \@hangfrom{\hskip #1}%
          \interlinepenalty \@M #5\@@par}%
    \endgroup
  \else
    \def\@svsechd{#4{\hskip #1\relax #5}}%
  \fi
  \@xsect{#3}}
```

Note that it has/takes 5 arguments. `ifacconf` redefines `\@ssect` to take 6 arguments:

```
\def\@ssect#1#2#3#4#5#6{%
  \@tempskipa #4\relax
  \ifdim \@tempskipa>\z@
    \begingroup
      #5{%
        \@hangfrom{\hskip #2}%
          \interlinepenalty \@M \head@format{#1}{#6}\@@par}%
    \endgroup
  \else
    \def\@svsechd{#5{\hskip #2\relax \head@format{#1}{#6}}}%
  \fi
  \@xsect{#4}}
```

`hyperref` doesn't know that this, since it assumes the regular protocol (5 argument) exists even though packages/classes could (re)define their own sectional unit styles. It would be an unattainable task to accommodate for all possible versions of function (re)definitions.

The following approach stores `\@ssect` before `hyperref` redefines it. Then it's restored after `hyperref` is loaded, together with an insertion to accommodate for `nameref`'s title gab:

[image]

```
\documentclass{ifacconf}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{refs-test-delete.bib}
@Article{bibref1,
  author    = {Firstname M. Lastname},
  title     = {PaperTitle},
  journal   = {Journal of Journals},
  year      = {2009},
  volume    = {32},
  number    = {3},
  pages     = {1039--1045},
  month     = {5},
  publisher = {Publisher},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\makeatletter
\let\old@ssect\@ssect % Store how ifacconf defines \@ssect
\makeatother

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\def\@ssect#1#2#3#4#5#6{%
  \NR@gettitle{#6}% Insert key \nameref title grab
  \old@ssect{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}% Restore ifacconf's \@ssect
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}

\title{Paper Title\thanksref{titlenote}}

\thanks[titlenote]{
    Titlenote.
}

\author[First]{First Author}

\address[First]{First Author contact info.}

\begin{abstract}
The abstract.
\end{abstract}

\begin{keyword}
Keyword
\end{keyword}

\end{frontmatter}

\section{Introduction}
\label{sec:introduction}

Introduction.
This is based on the work of \citet{bibref1}.

\begin{ack}
Acknowledgement.
\end{ack}

\bibliography{refs-test-delete}

\end{document}
```