# Capacity exceeded error while using cleveref package with ifacconf class

Tags: cleveref

I am using the cleveref package with the ifacconf class and it is returning the error as follow:

```
TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000]. }{}
```

I could not identify the error. Can anybody help me?

My MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{ifacconf}

\usepackage{graphicx,amsmath,url}     
\usepackage[round]{natbib}            

\usepackage[spanish,brazil,english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ae}

\usepackage{cleveref}


\begin{document}

\cref{here}

\begin{figure}
    \label{here}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class adds `section` to the reset list of the `part` counter, that it doesn't define.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{ifacconf}

\newcounter{part} % fix the issue in the class
\counterwithin*{section}{part}

\usepackage{graphicx,amsmath,url}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}

\usepackage[spanish,brazil,english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\cref{here}

\begin{figure}
  \caption{Caption}
  \label{here}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Note that the `ae` package is obsolete and should not be used in newer documents.

Comment: @Adriano I see no issue, so long as I load `varioref` *before* `cleveref`.

Comment: Its answer solved my problem. Thank you! 
But I would like to complement it, because I also needed to use varioref, hyperref packages, and I followed a recommendation according to [link](http://linorg.usp.br/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/cleveref/cleveref.pdf), page 25. 
There is a solution of a constraint while using hyperref package with ifacconf, according to [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/393690/illegal-unit-of-measure-error-when-using-hyperref-in-the-ifacconf-class). 
So I jointed all theses solutions into just one.