# Capacity exceeded error while using cleveref package with svjour3 (Springer) class

Tags: errors, cleveref, capacity

similiar to [Capacity exceeded error while using cleveref package with ifacconf class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/482167/capacity-exceeded-error-while-using-cleveref-package-with-ifacconf-class), the class svjour3 by Springer crashes together if the cleveref package is used.

```
(/compile/main.tex
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
\cl@chapter ->\cl@chapter 
                          \@elt {theorem}
l.2 \section{Introduction}
                          \label{sec:_Intro}
If you really absolutely need more capacity,
you can ask a wizard to enlarge me.


Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 11671 strings out of 492990
 202237 string characters out of 6132621
 628108 words of memory out of 5000000
 15072 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 14570 words of font info for 40 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 5000i,9n,39p,816b,746s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

The following example is an extraction of [this full template by Springer on overleaf](https://v2.overleaf.com/read/mfygrcvvqknr):

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}          % twocolumn

\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

How can that be fixed?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One way would be to tell `svjour3` to set up the `chapter` counter via the `numbook` option.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,numbook]{svjour3}          % twocolumn

\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

Alternatively you could remove the stub chapter definition the `svjour3` leaves which confused `cleverref`

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}          % twocolumn

\makeatletter
\let\cl@chapter\undefined
\makeatletter

\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

`svjour3` doesn't define chapter but specifies theorems are reset each chapter, which is normally harmless but confuses `cleveref`.

Comment: perfect! You made my day :)