# hyperref in title of ifacconf document disabled

Tags: hyperref, front-matter

Ii wanted to hyperlink a little symbol (the OCRID) in the list of authors but apparently hyperlinks are disabled in the frontmatter of the *ifacconf*-style. (I wanted to combine [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/533939/ifacconf-how-to-include-orcid-in-latex) and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/393690/illegal-unit-of-measure-error-when-using-hyperref-in-the-ifacconf-class) post)

Any idea if my hypothetis is correct and how to fool it?

```
%===============================================================================
% $Id: ifacconf.tex 19 2011-10-27 09:32:13Z jpuente $  
% Template for IFAC meeting papers
% Copyright (c) 2007-2008 International Federation of Automatic Control
%===============================================================================
\documentclass{ifacconf}


\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%===============================================================================
\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}
    \title{The hard of gold}        

    \author[AAA] {Zaphod Beeblebrox\href{https://www.duckduckgo.com}{CLICK ME}}
    \author[Earth]{Arthur Dent}
    \author[AAA] {Ford Perfect}

    \address[AAA]{\href{https://www.openstreetmaps.org}{CLICK ME}}
    \address[Earth]{....}
\end{frontmatter}
test
\end{document}
```

The IFAC template can be downloaded [here](https://www.ifac-control.org/events/resolveuid/b0e4734736878819db179d76290a8f78) (coming from this site https://www.ifac-control.org/events/authors-guide) -- which includes the *ifacconf.cls*.

Comment: well I will not download a large template and debug it. But your url in the \href is wrong, you are missing the protocol https://.

Comment: thx @UlrikeFischer, I fixed that but it was just the MVE that was wrong. I understand the effort to download a template causes, but style-classes are far out of my skills. I would like to know if they ever update this as it must cause pain all over the community. anyway, thx for the hint

Comment: sorry but either they don't want links there, then don't do it, or you are doing it wrong, then check the documentation or ask them for support, or it is broken then report it and ask that they repair their class. That the latex community sometimes offers work arounds or hacks or support to handle such classes doesn't mean  that the class writer has no responsability at all.

Comment: ouch. You presume that I didn't even try and use this community as a coding/fixing service...

Comment: I know that you tried. But yes you are using this community as a fixing service. Or what else it the question about? Perhaps you are lucky and someone comes along who either already knows the problem or has some free time and the will to look at it. But in generally I don't like it much that more and more people simply link to some external template and ask how to handle it. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/391022/2388

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?  I have the same problem.  As soon as I add `\usepackage{hyperref}` to the header thousands of errors appear, starting at the `\author` commands.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution here:

https://github.com/forgi86/sysid-transfer-functions-pytorch/blob/main/doc/paper/ms.tex

```latex
\documentclass{ifacconf}

...

\usepackage{url}            % simple URL typesetting

...

\begin{document}

...

The linear dynamical operator has been implemented in the  \emph{PyTorch} deep learning framework
   and the software is available for download at  \url{https://github.com/forgi86/sysid-transfer-functions-pytorch}.

...

\end{document}
```

(Thanks to Marco Forgione et al. for making the Latex document of their paper publicly available.)